# Tasks not running properly - Windows Server 2019

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I'm in the process of standing up a Windows Server 2019 system primarily used for running scripts via task scheduler. The scripts that have been working on the 2016 2012 servers before it no longer work on the new server. I have written simple scripts to see what specifically is not working and was wondering if anyone has seen this before.

```
test-wsman $DFSIPADDRESS | tee-object -variable test | out-file errortest.log
$test | out-file \\$DFSIPADDRESS\my\personal\share\wsmantest.log
$error | out-file errortest.log
```

The error output indicates that the user "has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer." for the out-file to the DFS. If I run the same script as the user in ISE it works fine. If I run the script through task scheduler but require the user to be logged in it also works.

The user is a domain user and in the local admin group. I have verified log on as a batch for the user.

I have verified batch logon. It's as if the user is not getting domain access when the script is run via task scheduler, but does still have local admin rights.

any thoughts would be very appreciated.

EDIT: I have updated the title to reflect that it is any task not just powershell scripts. I cannot access any remote resources within the task with saved credentials. I see NT Authority\Anonymous logins on the remote server(s) and the script returns unauthorized access.

Comment: Seems like your service account doesn't seem to have permissions to run scheduled tasks, did you see if it's added at least as `Log on as a batch job` ? In addition to that, you should the absolute path where the files are going to be saved to avoid further errors.

Comment: I am using absolute paths in the actual script and it works saving locally even to paths restricted to admin access it seems only domain privileges aren't being extended. The log on as batch job is set with both the user specifically (added when troubleshooting) and the administrators group which the user is a member of.

Comment: https://danblee.com/log-on-as-batch-job-rights-for-task-scheduler/log-on-as-batch-job-rights/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few likely culprits to generate this error. These first three are unlikely if you can access the file share with that user manually:

- The AD user has the `LogonWorkstations` attribute set, limiting its ability to connect remotely.
- On the local machine, the `Allow Log On Locally` policy is set to specific users.
- On the remote machine, `Access this computer from the network` is set to specific users

Go ahead and check these though:

- The local machine doesn't allow `Log on as a batch job`, which you mention you've checked (make sure you have restarted if you changed this). Verify that there is not a difference between the **domain** group policies and the **local** group policy that may be overriding your settings.
- In the security options of the task, the `Do not store password` option is enabled.

---

Also try creating a very basic task, running as that user, set to `only run while user is logged in`, with something like this to see if it connects successfully:

```
Action: Powershell.exe
Args:   -c "Hello" | Out-File \\server\share\hello.txt
```

Comment: It does work if the "only run while user is logged in" is checked and it runs properly. It runs if it's not checked, but is unable to write (authenticate?) to any network shares. I don't believe the problem is with the account due to it being the account I'm using on the current server.  
  
`LogonWorkstations` - `<not set>`  
`Deny Log On Locally` - set to groups this account is 100% not a member of (enterprise admins/domain admins/guests)

Comment: allow logon locally is set to administrators and the account is a member of local administrators.  access from network is set to authenticated users and administrators which the account is a member of both.  log on as batch job is set and the server has been rebooted multiple times.  password storage is allowed for this server via GPO and in fact is working.  the scripts run they just can't do anything requiring network authentication (e.g. access shares/access SQL servers). I've used Microsoft Policy Analyzer to try to find the diffs, but there don't seem to be any other than os version.

Comment: @JoshuaPape If it runs fine 'while user is logged in', then it's almost definitely `Allow/Deny Logon as Batch Job`'s fault or something similar. Note that domain gpo overrides local here, and they *don't* combine. Try dumping the domain group policy with `gpresult /h c:\folder\gpresult.html`, and dig through the applied settings for clues. There are **many** finicky settings, like limiting which credentials can be forwarded.

Comment: Thanks, I've pulled gpresults for both systems and they seem to be identical at first lookover. I will be looking deeper to see if I can find any inconsistencies. I was already using microsoft policy analyzer which allows for comparison more easily and shows effective state vs baselines.

Comment: @JoshuaPape It's more digging, but you may be able to find security or system event logs denying access to that user with some more information. For what it's worth, I am able to run your script as a scheduled task on a 2019 server, and it is able to write out to a domain file server successfully.

Comment: OK, so upon investigating the GPOs being applied/denied the policy to disable the deny storage of passwords was not being applied. But, it wasn't being applied to either machine and according to the RSOP/gpresult it wasn't being set so should have been defaulting to disabled. I have corrected the issue and the GPO is being applied and I have rebooted the system. There is no change to the behavior. I'm still able to run tasks when the user is logged on, but lose all access to remote systems/services when the task is set to run whether or not the user is logged on.

Comment: I'm elevating this up to my higher level guys to see if they can see something in AD or something blocking something.... the interesting thing to me is I ran `[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current | out-file e:\uc.log` and it comes back that it's running in domain context and is pulling all the info from AD...